# Using log4cxx for logging a particular class in C++

Tags: c++, logging, log4cxx

Following is my sample log4cxx configuration file which I use in my project -

```
# Set root logger level to INFO and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A1

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %X{pname}:%X{pid} %-5p %l- %m%n
log4j.appender.A1.serverFileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

# Tweak the timestamp format so that it sorts easier
log4j.appender.A1.serverFileAppender.fileName=/tmp/client_cpp.log
```

Currently, the `rootLogger` is set to `INFO`. Is there a way to configure it such that it only logs `DEBUG` messages in certain .cpp files? For example, I have a `Consumer.cpp` file which has a few log messages with `DEBUG` level. How can I configure it so that it only logs `DEBUG` messages from that file? I went through the tutorial [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/Log4cxx.html), but didn't file the relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding following line in the log4cxx.conf file -

```
log4j.category.ProducerImpl=DEBUG
```